# How to use object type data for a in clause in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I have a type declaration as below

```
CREATE TYPE ip_usr_lbl AS OBJECT (user_id     VARCHAR2(30));
```

I have a type table creates as below

```
CREATE  TYPE ip_lst_dtl IS TABLE OF ip_usr_lbl;

O_usr_lbl ip_lst_dtl;
```

I have 20 users id in O_usr_lbl;

How can I use this in the query as below.

```
select emp_id from
employee where emp_name in (select user_id from table(O_usr_lbl));
```

I tried creating a function to return object as an output and using

```
select user_id from table(function(IN));
```

but it didn't work.

Expect to query employee table using `USER_ID IN object O_usr_tbl`

Comment: Show function's text, please

Answer (score 2):

> How can I use this in the query as below.
>
> select emp_id from employee where emp_name in (select user_id from
>   table(O_usr_lbl));

If your intention is to use the `Object` type in scope of `SQL` as plain `Select` statement as shown above then its not possible to do so.

You can use the `object` as `table` operator under the scope of `PLSQL` as shown below:

```
declare
  --Created a list of users. 
  o_usr_lbl   ip_lst_dtl := ip_lst_dtl(ip_usr_lbl('SMITH'),ip_usr_lbl('ALLEN') );
  v_var       ip_lst_dtl;
begin

  select ip_usr_lbl(empno) 
  bulk collect into v_var -- Holding the result set to a variable
  from emp
  where ename in (select user_id from table ( o_usr_lbl ));

  --Displaying the result
  for i in 1..v_var.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(v_var(i).user_id);
  end loop;

end;
```

Output:

```
SQL> /
7369
7499

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

--Function can be written as

```
Create or replace function usr_dtls ( inpt IN ip_lst_dtl) 
return ip_lst_dtl is
  v_var   ip_lst_dtl;
begin
  select ip_usr_lbl(empno) 
  bulk collect into
    v_var
  from emp
  where ename 
  in (
    select user_id from table ( inpt )
  );
  return v_var;
end;
```

--Execution of function

```
SQL> select * from table (usr_dtls(ip_lst_dtl(ip_usr_lbl('SMITH'),ip_usr_lbl('ALLEN') )));

USER_ID
------------------------------
7369
7499
```

OR

```
declare
  o_usr_lbl   ip_lst_dtl := ip_lst_dtl(ip_usr_lbl('SMITH'),ip_usr_lbl('ALLEN') );
  v_var       ip_lst_dtl;
begin
   v_var := usr_dtls(inpt =>o_usr_lbl);
   --Displaying the result

  for i in 1..v_var.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(v_var(i).user_id);
  end loop;
end;
```